# How to use pg_search_scope with Mobility for translated attributes?

Tags: internationalization, pg-search, mobility

how can i use pg_search_scope in combination with Mobility for translated attributes? Available languages are :de and :en. Searching for category names return empty results. There mus be a way to search for locale_accessors, in my case it should be name_de || name_en depending on current i18n.locale settings.

Here's my controller method:

```rb
def index
  @categories = params[:query].present? ? Category.search(params[:query]) : Category.all.includes(%i[string_translations])
end
```

Here's my model:

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :name, type: :string

  include PgSearch::Model

  pg_search_scope :search,
                  against: [:name],
                  using: {
                    trigram: { threshold: 0.3, word_similarity: true }
                  }
end
```

Here's my mobility config:

```rb
Mobility.configure do
  # PLUGINS
  plugins do
    # Backend
    #
    # Sets the default backend to use in models. This can be overridden in models
    # by passing +backend: ...+ to +translates+.
    #
    # To default to a different backend globally, replace +:key_value+ by another
    # backend name.
    #
    backend :key_value

    # ActiveRecord
    #
    # Defines ActiveRecord as ORM, and enables ActiveRecord-specific plugins.
    active_record

    # Accessors
    #
    # Define reader and writer methods for translated attributes. Remove either
    # to disable globally, or pass +reader: false+ or +writer: false+ to
    # +translates+ in any translated model.
    #
    reader
    writer

    # Backend Reader
    #
    # Defines reader to access the backend for any attribute, of the form
    # +<attribute>_backend+.
    #
    backend_reader
    #
    # Or pass an interpolation string to define a different pattern:
    # backend_reader "%s_translations"

    # Query
    #
    # Defines a scope on the model class which allows querying on
    # translated attributes. The default scope is named +i18n+, pass a different
    # name as default to change the global default, or to +translates+ in any
    # model to change it for that model alone.
    #
    query

    # Cache
    #
    # Comment out to disable caching reads and writes.
    #
    cache

    # Dirty
    #
    # Uncomment this line to include and enable globally:
    # dirty
    #
    # Or uncomment this line to include but disable by default, and only enable
    # per model by passing +dirty: true+ to +translates+.
    # dirty false

    # Fallbacks
    #
    # Uncomment line below to enable fallbacks, using +I18n.fallbacks+.
    # fallbacks
    #
    # Or uncomment this line to enable fallbacks with a global default.
    # fallbacks { :pt => :en }

    # Presence
    #
    # Converts blank strings to nil on reads and writes. Comment out to
    # disable.
    #
    presence

    # Default
    #
    # Set a default translation per attributes. When enabled, passing +default:
    # 'foo'+ sets a default translation string to show in case no translation is
    # present. Can also be passed a proc.
    #
    # default 'foo'

    # Fallthrough Accessors
    #
    # Uses method_missing to define locale-specific accessor methods like
    # +title_en+, +title_en=+, +title_fr+, +title_fr=+ for each translated
    # attribute. If you know what set of locales you want to support, it's
    # generally better to use Locale Accessors (or both together) since
    # +method_missing+ is very slow.  (You can use both fallthrough and locale
    # accessor plugins together without conflict.)
    #
    # fallthrough_accessors

    # Locale Accessors
    #
    # Uses +def+ to define accessor methods for a set of locales. By default uses
    # +I18n.available_locales+, but you can pass the set of locales with
    # +translates+ and/or set a global default here.
    #
    locale_accessors
    #
    # Or define specific defaults by uncommenting line below
    # locale_accessors [:en, :ja]

    # Attribute Methods
    #
    # Adds translated attributes to +attributes+ hash, and defines methods
    # +translated_attributes+ and +untranslated_attributes+ which return hashes
    # with translated and untranslated attributes, respectively. Be aware that
    # this plugin can create conflicts with other gems.
    #
    # attribute_methods
  end
end
```

Is it possible and how it works?
Thank you very much for help me out in this case!

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: No sorry, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic scope with lambda and return the config hash with the query:

```rb
pg_search_scope :search, lambda { |query|
                                 {
                                   against:  ["name_#{I18n.locale}".to_sym],
                                   trigram:  { threshold: 0.3, word_similarity: true },
                                   ignoring: :accents,
                                   query:    query
                                 }
                               }
```